# How to calculate height between the very top of a div and bottom: 0

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to be able to place a `div` on top are under another `div`. With the example in the image i have two `div`s. The first one is postioned with `right: 10px;` and `bottom: 10px;`. I want to be able to position the second `div` in the same way, but so `bottom` is `10px` higher than the very top of the first `div`. To do that dynamically I need to have the height difference between the very top of the first `div` and `bottom: 0`.

How can I get that with JavaScript or JQuery?

[image]

```
<div class="div1">This is the first div</div>
<div class="div2">This is the second div</div>
```

```
.div1 {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #990;
}
.div2 {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #099;
    //position: absolute;
    //right: 10px;
    //bottom: ...;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `display: flex` along with `flex-direction: column-reverse`. And for 10px gap you can use `margin-bottom:10px`  for all divs.

See the Snippet below:

```css
.main{
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  
}
.div{
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.div:first-child{
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
.div1 {
    background-color: #990;
}
.div2 {
    background-color: #099;   
}
.div3 {
    background-color: #909;   
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="div div1">This is the first div</div>
  <div class="div div2">This is the second div</div>
  <div class="div div3">This is the third div</div>
</div>
```

You can also test it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/nimittshah/82jv9bhx/)

Comment: It's better to add this margin-bottom:0 with .main :first-child {margin-bottom: 0;}

Comment: Sure, but it should be `.div:frist-child{ margin-bottom: 0}` not `.main..` :)

Answer (score 2):

In js, access that first div offsetHeight and add 10px to it. You  get the height for second div.

el.offsetHeight + 10;

In jQuery, $(el).getBoundingClientRect() gives height of the element.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, you can use clientHeight to get the height of `div1`, add whatever number you want to it and set that as a variable that you can use to style your div2's `bottom` position.

It's also advisable to add `box-sizing: border-box` to your CSS to help avoid any random positioning/sizing bugs.

```js
const div1 = document.querySelector(".div1");
const div2 = document.querySelector(".div2");

// Here we are creating the new 'position' variable //
let position = div1.clientHeight + 20;

// Here we are styling div2's bottom position with the above variable.//
// You can use whatever unit you want from here.//
div2.style.bottom = position + "px";
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.div1 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background-color: #990;
}
.div2 {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  padding: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  background-color: #099;
}
```

```html
  <div class="div1">
    <p>Div 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    <p>Div 2</p>
  </div>
```